# Troubleshooting mysql Query

Tags: mysql, echo

I'm having trouble with querying this simple table with a passed in variable:
[image]

Here is the relevant code:

```
// MySQL connection saved to variable $db
// variable $item is passed in as the string "Camera1"

$accessQuery = "SELECT Available FROM inventory WHERE Item = '" . $item . "'";

// This outputs properly as "SELECT Available FROM inventory WHERE Item = 'Camera1'"
echo $accessQuery; 

if($oldVal = mysqli_query($db, $accessQuery)){
    echo $oldVal // Should be 5 - but there is no output
    // echo 'Made it inside if statement' --- This line outputs correctly
}
else{
    echo 'Error accessing MySQL query';
}
```

Comment: So is it echoing "Error accessing MySQL query" or something else?

Comment: Nope, it gets inside the if clause - I can `echo 'Made it inside if'` for example.

Comment: You need to call `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, which returns an associative array of the row contents, and then access the element of the array. Have you bothered to look at any documentation or tutorials?

Comment: What happens if you echo the query result?

Comment: That's what I'm doing with `echo $oldVal` isn't it? I get an error associated with server response.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call a `mysqli_fetch_XXX` function to get the resulting data from the query.

```
if($result = mysqli_query($db, $accessQuery)){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $oldVal = $row['Available'];
    echo $oldVal // Should be 5 - but $oldVal causes an error when I try to output
}
else{
    echo 'Error accessing MySQL query: ' . mysqli_error($db);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$accessQuery = "SELECT Available FROM inventory WHERE Item = '" . $item . "'";



if($res = mysqli_query($db, $accessQuery)){



$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    $oldVal = $row['Available'];
    echo $oldVal;

}
else{
    echo 'Error accessing MySQL query';
}
```